# Create key/value type from object type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say we have a type

```
type Foo = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}
```

I now want to define a type for an object having a `key` and a `value` of a given type `T`, so that the type of the value is directly inferred from the key, so that I can do:

```
const kv1: KeyValue<Foo> = {key: 'a', value: 'STRING'};
const kv2: KeyValue<Foo> = {key: 'b', value: 42};
const kv3: KeyValue<Foo> = {key: 'c', value: true};
```

If I simply do this:

```
type KeyValue<T> = {
  key: keyof T;
  value: T[keyof T]
}
```

... then obviously the values will be the union of all properties' values in `Foo`:

And if I do this:

```
type KeyValue<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  key: K;
  value: T[K]
}
```

... then sure, if explicitly typed as `KeyValue<Foo, 'a'>` I can create object literals that match the type of `Foo`:s properties, but if I don't specifically provide the type AND the key for each literal but simply do `KeyValue<Foo, keyof Foo>`, each value will be allowed to be of the type of any of the values in `Foo`, i.e., all values will be `string | number | boolean` instead of being inferred from the entered `key`.

In the end I want to be able to do things like this:

```
const kvs: Array<KeyValue<Foo>> = [
  {key: 'a', value: 'STRING'}, // should not compile if value is a number or boolean
  {key: 'b', value: 42}, // should not compile if value is a string or boolean
  {key: 'c', value: true}, // should not compile if value is a string or number
];
```

Is it possible to derive the `KeyValue` type with these constraints, so that effectively it becomes `KeyValue<Foo, 'a'> | KeyValue<Foo, 'b'> | KeyValue<Foo, 'c'>` in the second example above, without having to manually write this union? Basically I guess what I'd like is to be able to infer the type of `value` from the value of `key` in the current literal object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot represent each key-value pair using the single `KeyValue` object, since this would require either partial inference (for the key) or somehow referring to the `key` property from `value` property inside the same object.

However, what you could do is create a discriminated union using the input object.

```
type Foo = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}

type KeyValue<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: {
    key: P;
    value: T[P];
  }
}[keyof T];

// with KeyValue<Foo>, this generates the following type
// 
// {
//     key: "a";
//     value: string;
// } | {
//     key: "b";
//     value: number;
// } | {
//     key: "c";
//     value: boolean;
// }

const kvs: Array<KeyValue<Foo>> = [
  {key: 'a', value: 40}, // ERROR
  {key: 'b', value: true}, // ERROR
  {key: 'c', value: "foo"}, // ERROR
];
```

Comment: Damn, now _that's_ smart! Kudos!